# Sorting the dataset object using dataset.tables.select method

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

please help me regarding this block of code...
i have a table that has these fields (cCLID,cCLID,nLID)
nLID is a numeric, but when I sort it the result show this sequence (1,10,2,3,4,5...)
but i want to sort it this way (1,2,3,4,5...10)

```
sDataSet.Tables(tmp(0).Name).Select("cCLID='" & _cCLID.Text_Value & "'", "Convert(Numberic(18,0),nLID) ASC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temp-Field like Sort_NLID and fill it in SQL like:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(NLID) = 1 THEN CAST(NLID AS INTEGER) ELSE -1 END AS Sort_NLID
```

then sort

```
sDataSet.Tables(tmp(0).Name).Select("cCLID='" & _cCLID.Text_Value & "'", "Sort_NLID, nLID")
```